# timthumb.php returns a 404 error after server upgrade

Tags: php, chmod

I have recently made some changes to my hosting account and a script I was using which utilizes timthumb now returns a 404. In the log it shows a Premature end of script warning.

I have tried the usual CHMOD 0777 for the main folder to ensure it is writable and the url to the files is ok but still no joy.

Anyone have any other suggestions I should try?

Comment: We'd need more details probably... Lots of questions popped up after reading your problem description:) What changes you did to an account? Do you use mod_rewrite? Isn't there an issue with headers and content-type inside of titthumb.php? Is php version same as it was on old account hosting? Do you have all php modules titthumb use on new account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you performed the server maintenance did you do it under the root account.

i.e. Have you by mistake set the ownership of the folder used by TimThumb to "root"?

I had a customer do this as the solution is to simply CHOWN the folder to another non root account.

Hope this helps

Gaz

Comment: Doh! How could I make such a rudimentary mistake as that. Yes Gary, CHOWN'ing to another account fixed it. Many Many Thanks !!!!!